# Does “Asrock G31M-S R2.0” supports “Core 2 Extreme QX9650” processor or FSB1600 MHz CPUs?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, bios

My motherboard is "**Asrock G31M-S R2.0**"
which supports CPU Socket type **LGA 775**.
http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/G31M-S%20R2.0/

If you open an official web page of "Asrock G31M-S R2.0" then you can see that there is written:
"Compatible with all FSB1600/1333/1066/800 MHz CPUs"
But if you click the button "**CPU Support List**" then you can see that there is no any CPU listed in the list which supports FSB1600
http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/G31M-S%20R2.0/?cat=CPU
So I need to know:
1) Does “Asrock G31M-S R2.0” supports FSB1600 MHz CPUs?
2) If it supports then tell me which one is that kind of CPU, just show me any of them!
3) I know that "Core 2 Extreme QX9650" **FSB** Speed is 1333 but it was not listed in the "CPU Support List" I need to know why?
4) If “Asrock G31M-S R2.0” which has "**G31** + **ICH7**" Chipsets  does not support "**Core 2 QX9650**" then tell me just why? Please!
Is the problem about BIOS? Is it necessary to update it? Is the problem about **TDP**? Core 2 QX9650 has TDP 130w
http://ark.intel.com/products/33921/Intel-Core2-Extreme-Processor-QX9650-12M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB
5) Can you tell me which kind of requirement must satisfy motherboard in order to support "Core 2 Extreme QX9650" processor (excluding Chipsets and Sockets)

Comment: this CPU and architecture is too old, that it make no sense to upgrade. Buy a haswell i5 + motherboard + RAM .

Comment: It is not about updating PC or CPU! It is not about money! It is not about performance! It is only theory - The knowledge of PC!

Answer (score 1):

1. I think they wrote 1600 MHz just for marketing purposes, as there's no 1600 FSB CPU listed on the compatability test.
2. The best CPU it supports is Core 2 Quad QX6800 with 1066 FSB speed.
3. Not everything depends on FSB. There are many other things to list, like: CPU architecture, manufacturing technology, socket type (ceramic, organic and other), core version, cache, TDP and many other minor things.
4. Chipsets aren't the only things that decide which CPU is supported and which is not. It depends on the manufacturer.
   Yeah, it may be the high TDP that motherboard wasn't intended to handle. And updating the BIOS won't help you at all.
5. No. You can't do anything but buy an another motherboard that supports your QX9650.